# for loops in Mule 3.8.4 | Dataweave 1.0

Tags: string, for-loop, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I need to do a **string comparison** on the incoming payload string with the existing list of product names from cache, as there will not be a exact match, first I need to remove last 3 chars from the incoming payload string and do a comparison with all the existing strings/product Names.
If I find a match then do other transformation.
 else remove one more char from incoming payload string and compare again. 
I need to repeat this till the string size of incoming payload is =3 (no need to compare if the string size is less than 3)

Summary: i need to remove chars from right to left and do a string comparison

Imput Payload is as below:

```
{
  "productPartNo": "MPN-400110",
  "supplier": "70058",
  "productCode": "02",
}
```

Need to compare the string "productPartNo" against the "partNumber" field from the below existing product list

```
{
  "Product": [
    {
      "productNumber": "420475",
      "created": "2012-10-28",
      "partNumber": "C1F2PNEX71K9",
      "codeNo": "7712",
      "manufacturer": ""
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "478376",
      "created": "2017-12-12",
      "partNumber": "N77-C77-RMK=",
      "codeNo": "1589",
      "manufacturer": "50884"
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "478381",
      "created": "2017-12-12",
      "partNumber": "CON-U-C1F2PXNE",
      "codeNo": "1586",
      "manufacturer": "50884"
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "478384",
      "created": "2017-12-12",
      "partNumber": "PMPN4070",
      "codeNo": "1585",
      "manufacturer": "50884"
    }
 ]
}
```

In this case, my input string "productPartNo": "MPN-400110" should be compared with all the PartNumber.
After removing chars from last, the string 'MPN' will have the match/contain with the "partNumber": "PMPN4070" hence I should get the "codeNo": "1585" associated with partNumber-PMPN4070  as my output field.

How can I implement this logic in %dw 1.0

Comment: Please provide with sample input data and expected output.  Then I can provide you with a solution.  Nonetheless, you can strip the last three characters of a string with `[0 to -3]`; this is the Range Selector, here's the documentation for it.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-selectors#range-selector.  You can iterate using the `map` operator; here's the documentation for it: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-operators#map

Comment: Thanks George for the response. I have updated the post with sample input and output data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This needed a little thinking and its late, not much brain power left, in the morning I may revise but its a good start given your sample data.  Just let me know if you have any further clarifications.

Just copy and paste inside a `Transform Message` processor and turn on the preview.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/dw

%var products = {
  "Product": [
    {
      "productNumber": "420475",
      "created": "2012-10-28",
      "partNumber": "C1F2PNEX71K9",
      "codeNo": "7712",
      "manufacturer": ""
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "478376",
      "created": "2017-12-12",
      "partNumber": "N77-C77-RMK=",
      "codeNo": "1589",
      "manufacturer": "50884"
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "478381",
      "created": "2017-12-12",
      "partNumber": "CON-U-C1F2PXNE",
      "codeNo": "1586",
      "manufacturer": "50884"
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "478384",
      "created": "2017-12-12",
      "partNumber": "PMPN4070",
      "codeNo": "1585",
      "manufacturer": "50884"
    }
 ]
}


%var inputPayload = {
  "productPartNo": "MPN-400110",
  "supplier": "70058",
  "productCode": "02"
}
---
// Get a list with all the substrings to search with--this give you the following array
// ["MPN-400","MPN-40","MPN-4","MPN-","MPN"]
(4 to (sizeOf inputPayload.productPartNo ) - 2 map inputPayload.productPartNo[0 to -$]
map (
    // Filter the list of products on the substring, 
    // this should either give you a matches or the empty list
    // Finally, take the first match.  I am not sure if this what you want.
    (products.Product filter (e) -> (e.partNumber contains $))[0]
) 
filter ($ != null))[0].codeNo
```

Comment: Thanks George, It's a great idea to create an array with all the strings which needs to be comared. it would be really helpful if you can provide logic to create the array as below. ["MPN-400","MPN-40","MPN-4","MPN-","MPN"]

Comment: Easy just use this portion: `4 to (sizeOf inputPayload.productPartNo ) - 2 map inputPayload.productPartNo[0 to -$]`